# Problems replacing substring from parsed spanish language tweets - R 2.15.3

Tags: r, twitter, xml-parsing, substring, gsub

Here is the complete code to extract the tweets: load required package

```
require(XML)
```

Let's get some tweets about the #18A hash tag define twitter search url (following the atom standard)

```
twitter_url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?"
```

encode query

```
query = URLencode("#18A")
```

vector to store results

```
tweets = character(0)
```

paginate 17 times to harvest tweets

```
for (page in 1:17)
{
twitter_search = paste(twitter_url, "q=", query,
"&rpp=100&lang=es&pagegeocode=-34.686173,-58.648529,15mi", page, sep="")
tmp = xmlParseDoc(twitter_search, asText=F)
tweets = c(tweets, xpathSApply(tmp, "//s:entry/s:title",
                         xmlValue, namespaces=c('s'='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom')))
}

print(tweets)
class(tweets)

Then, replacing the spanish characters (á, é, í,..) isn't working.

tweets = gsub("<U\\+00E1>", "a", tweets)
tweets = gsub("<U\\+00E9>", "e", tweets)
```

We can see how the result is not correct in the 1699 tweet

```
print(results[1699])
```

I've managed to "solve" the problem by changing the encoding of the tweets to:

```
Encoding(tweets) <- "ISO-8859"

# Replace spanish character with accent for "normal" character

tweets = gsub("\303\272", "u", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\303\241", "a", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\303\255", "i", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\303\263", "o", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\303\251", "e", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\303\271", "u", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\303\201", "O", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\303\211", "E", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\342\234\224", "", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\302\241", "", tweets)
tweets = gsub("\302\277", "", tweets)
```

I guess there must be a better solution. I wonder why changing the encoding makes the gsub()
function work, and why it's not working in the previous tweets.

R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer i was looking for to solve the problem completely was the following: just changing the language of R. I had it in spanish and that was the source of the encoding issue with the tweets

The solution was just running this code in the Mac OSX terminal.

defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

In regex the `+` sign ahs special meaning.  You can use the `fixed = TRUE` argument to `gsub` or escape the special characters:

```
tweet = gsub("<U\\+00E9>", "e", tweet)
tweet = gsub("<U\\+00E1>", "a", tweet)
tweet = gsub("<U\\+00BF>", "" , tweet)


## [1] "RT @LuchoBugallo: Quieren una primicia? @CFKArgentina el #18A se va a      #Venezuela. Cual sera el motivo que la moviliza hacer un viaje d ..."
## [2] "RT @LuchoBugallo: #18A - Ya estan apareciendo las cuentas truchas de militontos, que usan s<U+00F3>lo en epoca de cacerolazos!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the option `fixed = TRUE` because `+` is probably screwing with the regex:

```
tweet = gsub("<U+00E9>", "e", tweet, fixed = T)
tweet = gsub("<U+00E1>", "a", tweet, fixed = T)
tweet = gsub("<U+00BF>", "" , tweet, fixed = T)
```